# Adding ArcGIS Mapserver layer - query returned no layers

Tags: qgis-3

I am attempting to connect to an ArcGIS Mapserver that has worked without any problems in the past and now for some reason when trying to connect to the service it indicates "query returned no layers". I have contacted the administrator and the url I was using now redirects to the one listed below but other than that it works on his end with ESRI products.

Can someone verify the url and check to see if it works?

https://nsgiwa.novascotia.ca/arcgis/rest/services/BASE/BASE_NSODB_10k_WM84/MapServer

Comment: Did NS patch their 10.5.1 services with this TLS patch https://support.esri.com/en/download/7666  source https://nsgiwa.novascotia.ca/arcgis/rest/services - there might be a bug in the patch for none esri connections (just a hunch).

Comment: I did check with the server admin and no changes were made other than a redirect, the TLS patch for ArcGIS desktop has not been applied to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS 3.6 (Noosa) had to get the WMTS layer data to pull in to QGIS

(The MapServer/FeatureServer doesn't seem to be setup quite right for QGIS. Hence
I had to use the WMTS layer)

> https://nsgiwa.novascotia.ca/arcgis/rest/services/BASE/BASE_NSODB_10k_WM84/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I can confirm WMTS works on my end also. It is strange that other mapservers from the same organization seem to work as expected.

Comment: In addition to be sure the tiles display properly and look sharp the spatial reference of QGIS should be set to that of the service, in this case 3857.